# SharePoint Survey Branching

Tags: survey

I am trying to create a survey in the following format:

Q1 - Yes/No

If the answer to Q1 is Yes -

Q2 - Test
Q3 - Test

End Survey

If the answer to Q1 is No -

Q4 - Test

End Survey

But when I select Yes to Q1 it goes through Q2 and Q3 but then goes to Q4 which should only show up if I select No to Q1 and then the survey should end.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a good way to set up branching logic is to first build all the questions then circle back and edit the existing questions to apply the branching logic. Also be sure to add page separators between questions that should not be on the same page. Give it another try and see if this helps.

Example:

Q1

(page separator)

Q2

(page separator)

Q3

(page separator)

Q4